# Why am I getting an InvalidOperationException when trying to re-attach an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, detach

I had a bit of a struggle trying to understand why my code was crashing (which I got to work).

When you look at both the original method and the working one, the placement of one line is different

```
ctx.Inventories.Attach(this);
```

I'm puzzled when the original method doesn't work but the second one does. 
Can anyone provide some insight?

Here's the exception that I get.

System.InvalidOperationException : An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

This is my original method

```
  public void RemoveDependency(int depId)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        if (this.Id != 0 && depId > 0)
        {
            using (ApsEntities ctx = new ApsEntities())
            {
                var query2 = from d in ctx.Dependencies
                             where d.Id == depId
                             select d;

                Dependency found = query2.FirstOrDefault();

                if (found != null)
                {
                **ctx.Inventories.Attach(this);**
                    ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(this, EntityState.Modified);
                    this.Dependencies.Remove(found);

                   ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Here is my working method

```
public void RemoveDependency(int depId)
{
    bool returnValue = false;

    if (this.Id != 0 && depId > 0)
    {
        using (ApsEntities ctx = new ApsEntities())
        {
            **ctx.Inventories.Attach(this);**

            var query2 = from d in ctx.Dependencies
                         where d.Id == depId
                         select d;

            Dependency found = query2.FirstOrDefault();

            if (found != null)
            {
                ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(this, EntityState.Modified);
                this.Dependencies.Remove(found);

               ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Common refrain: Define "doesn't work". If it's an exception, post the exception. If it is undesirable behavior, post the desirable behavior and what the actual result is.

Comment: Sorry Chris, I've attached it.  It slipped my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior has to do with the `ObjectStateManager` tracking the relationships.

When the current `Inventory` item is not known to the `ObjectContext` (as in your first example) then the relationships between `Inventory` and `Dependency` is not recognized by the context. Since `Inventory` is unknown to the `ObjectContext` your query for a `Inventory` will load it and the item already exists when you attach it to your `ObjectContext`.

In the second example you first attach `Inventory` and then execute the query. The `ObjectContext` will then explicitly attach the `Dependency` object to the `Inventory` item.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx) states:

> ObjectStateManager tracks query results, and provides logic to merge
>   multiple overlapping query results. It also performs in-memory change
>   tracking when a user inserts, deletes, or modifies objects, and
>   provides the change set for updates. This change set is used by the
>   change processor to persist modifications.

This behavior can't happen when the related objects are not known to the `ObjectContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  I'll keep this in the back on my head in the future to make sure it never happens again.